# Android ToolBar icon positioning

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

I am trying to recreate this menu setup in Android:

[image]

But I can only get this:

[image]

I can't seem to get rid of the WebBrowser text in the toolbar without the app crashing. Additionally I can't space out the icons.

There is a small Progress bar between the forward and back buttons.

Any help?

Here is my menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="net.txisystems.txiwebbrowser.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_house"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forward"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Placing the progress bar in my activity_main.xml under the toolbar I get this:

[image]

Here is the activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.txisystems.webbrowser.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To remove title use in your activity/fragment

   ```
   toolbar.setTitle(null)
   ```
2. You cannot put progressbar into menu.xml file
3. Use RelativeLayout inside Toolbar and put all views you need there like this:

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@drawable/gradient"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
   <ProgressBar
       android:indeterminate="true"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
       android:layout_width="28dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       android:layout_height="28dp"
       android:indeterminateTint="#fff"
       android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       />
   ```

Comment: edited my answer. having troubles with code formatting

Comment: Thanks but your suggestion doesn't allow me to space out icons. (home icon on the left, back and forward in the middle, and refresh on the right. When I put the progressbar in, it just expanded the toolbar and drop ped it on the left. See my revised question.

Comment: @Firemarble remove all menu elements and create this view like simple relative layout with gravies you need. You cannot make items right where you need using menu